# Failed to execute child process /snap/bin/jenkins (No such file or directory)

Tags: jenkins

I was trying to install Jenkins from the Ubuntu software , While I click on launch button getting the below error.

```
Error : There was an error creating the child process for this terminal.
```

Failed to execute child process "/snap/bin/jenkins" (No such file are directory).

```
rajasekhar@rajasekhar:/snap/bin$ ls -ltr
total 0

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun 10 21:05 jenkins.config -> /usr/bin/snap
rajasekhar@rajasekhar:/snap/bin$
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Please help me resolving the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First download package repository of Jenkins:

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then add the following entry in your /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/
```

Update your local package index, then finally install Jenkins:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

note: You will need to explicitly install a Java runtime environment, because Jenkins does not work with Java 9
**2.54 (2017-04) and newer: Java 8

1.612 (2015-05) and newer: Java 7**